# How can I run ajax code on browsers it does not work now?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

It works on localhost but does not work on real-time hosting
Please help with this code
my html goes like this ,

```
<div class="msg_box" style="left:5px">
  <div class="msg_head">chat

  </div>
  <div class="msg_wrap">
    <div class="msg_body" id="msg_body">
         <div  id="display_comment"></div>
         <div  id="msg"></div>
    </div>
     <form method="POST" id="comment_form">

     <input type="hidden" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('name') ?>" />


     <input type="hidden" name="idprod" id="idprod" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $prod_view->id; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
  <div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" name="comment_content" id="comment_content" rows="2"></textarea> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" /></div>
     </form>
</div>
</div>
```

The jquery code is as follows

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#comment_content').keypress(function (eventt) {

  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('#submit').submit();
    return false;    //<---- Add this line
  }
});


 $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/home/add_comment/",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '')
    {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val('0');

     load_comment();

    }
    $('#msg_body').animate({scrollTop: 6000000}, 600);


   }
  })
 });



$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('load_comment', 5000);

});
 load_comment();




var RefreshTimerInterval = 1000;

function load_comment()
 {

  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/home/fetch_comment/",
   method:"POST",
    data: {
      'idprod': $('#idprod').val()

                },
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment').html(data);
  setTimeout(load_comment, RefreshTimerInterval);
   }

  })
 }
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('load_comment', 500);
});
 $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
  var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
  $('#comment_name').focus();
 });

});



</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var RefreshTimerInterval = 1000; // every 5 seconds
    $(document).ready(getData);

    function getData() {
        $.get('<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'index.php/home/fetch_comment', function(data) {
             $('#display_comment').html(data);

             setTimeout(getData, RefreshTimerInterval);
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works on localhost but does not work on real-time hosting
Please help with this code
Is the error in the code or possible to have files js affected by this code

Comment: did you try to watch the console ?

Comment: Can you please specify the part "does not work"? Also, did you check the developer tools of your browser for JavaScript errors? Of the JavaScript code is bad the errors should pop up there. You can also use the same developer tools to check the "Network" tab. The AJAX request, including it's URL, should be visible there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which does not work is
keypress enter and submit   , I will try to look for javascript errors

Comment: Try to look at your base_url. e.g. "http://localhost/" or "http://yourdomain.com/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check your config.php file in config folder and make sure that line 26 is $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com';

And my suggestion is to use base_url this way:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#comment_content').keypress(function (eventt) {

  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('#submit').submit();
    return false;    //<---- Add this line
  }
});


 $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/add_comment'); ?>",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '')
    {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val('0');

     load_comment();

    }
    $('#msg_body').animate({scrollTop: 6000000}, 600);


   }
  })
 });



$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('load_comment', 5000);

});
 load_comment();




var RefreshTimerInterval = 1000;

function load_comment()
 {

  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/fetch_comment'); ?>",
   method:"POST",
    data: {
      'idprod': $('#idprod').val()

                },
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment').html(data);
  setTimeout(load_comment, RefreshTimerInterval);
   }

  })
 }
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('load_comment', 500);
});
 $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
  var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
  $('#comment_name').focus();
 });

});



</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var RefreshTimerInterval = 1000; // every 5 seconds
    $(document).ready(getData);

    function getData() {
        $.get("<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/fetch_comment'); ?>", function(data) {
             $('#display_comment').html(data);

             setTimeout(getData, RefreshTimerInterval);
        }
    }
</script>
```

If this doesn't help could you please leave error message here?